# SQL Statement is not returning the value to UNiX Variable

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, unix

I have shell script test_var.sh as below code. I am expecting the sysdate value in get_date variable but I am getting the empty line. I got the Sysdate value if I ran the same shell code in different server with same user/password. Please help me what changes required for Sever properties or user properties.

```
get_date=`sqlplus -s scott/Tiger@dbname <<EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
select to_char(Sysdate,"MM-DD-YYYY") from dual;
EOF`

echo $get_date
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Remove the `set feedback off` and `set pagesize 0` to see if any other error or feedback is given .

Comment: I have tested by removing the set parameters. still getting the null value.

Comment: And no other info ? Only a null value ?

Comment: just blank line.

Comment: when I remove -s , I got the below info.

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed Feb 12 15:42:31 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Comment: Try to put echo "$get_date"

Comment: I tried and its not working.

Comment: Issue is with Temp space in Unix server.Temp folder is full. After cleaning the Temp space, I am able to get the values from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put format in single quotes:

```
select to_char(Sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY') from dual;
```

Comment: I did, still not getting the value. I think the issue is with server or user profile. Because I am getting the value for the same script in another Server.

Comment: Issue is with Temp space in Unix server.Temp folder is full. After cleaning the Temp space, I am able to get the values from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete script:

cat d1.sh

```
get_date=`sqlplus -s xxx/xxx << EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
set newpage none
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) from dual;
EOF`

echo $get_date
```

And then if I run it:

```
$ sh d1.sh
2020-02-12
```

Comment: added the above statement.still getting the empty line.

Comment: I am getting the ouput in server1 but in server2.
About one month ago it worked in server2 also. somthing changes in server2 properties.

Comment: Can you log in to sqlplus and send the output of:  show all

Comment: SQL> show all;
appinfo is OFF and set to "SQL*Plus"
arraysize 15 | autocommit OFF | autoprint OFF | autorecovery OFF | autotrace OFF | blockterminator "." (hex 2e) | btitle OFF and is the first few characters of the next SELECT statement |
cmdsep OFF | colsep " " | compatibility version NATIVE | concat "." (hex 2e) | copycommit 0| COPYTYPECHECK is ON | define "&" (hex 26) | describe DEPTH 1 LINENUM OFF INDENT ON| echo OFF

Comment: Text is too large to send it.

Comment: Send email to bob.carlin@oracle.com

Comment: Let me know if you want see any particular parameter, i can post it here.

Comment: I need them all

Comment: Just split the output across multiple comments!

Comment: SQL> show all
appinfo is OFF and set to "SQL*Plus"
arraysize 15
autocommit OFF
autoprint OFF
autorecovery OFF
autotrace OFF
blockterminator "." (hex 2e)
btitle OFF and is the first few characters of the next SELECT statement
cmdsep OFF
colsep " "
compatibility version NATIVE
concat "." (hex 2e)
copycommit 0
COPYTYPECHECK is ONdefine "&" (hex 26)
describe DEPTH 1 LINENUM OFF INDENT ON
echo OFF
editfile "afiedt.buf"
embedded OFF
escape OFF

Comment: FEEDBACK ON for 6 or more rows
flagger OFF
flush ON
heading ON
headsep "|" (hex 7c)
instance "local"
linesize 80
lno 14
loboffset 1
logsource ""
long 80
longchunksize 80

Comment: newpage 1
null ""
numformat ""
numwidth 10
pagesize 14
PAUSE is OFF
pno 0
recsep WRAP
recsepchar " " (hex 20)
release 1102000200
repfooter OFF and is NULL
repheader OFF and is NULL
serveroutput OFF
shiftinout INVISIBLE
showmode OFF
spool OFF
sqlblanklines OFF
sqlcase MIXED
sqlcode 0
sqlcontinue "> "
sqlnumber ON
sqlpluscompatibility 10.2.0
sqlprefix "#" (hex 23)
sqlprompt "SQL> "
sqlterminator ";" (hex 3b)
suffix "sql"
tab ON
termout ON
timing OFF
trimout ON
trimspool OFF
ttitle OFF and is the first few characters of the next SELECT statement

Comment: underline "-" (hex 2d)
USER is "TGR"
verify ON
wrap : lines will be wrapped

Comment: There is one parameter "markup HTML OFF HEAD " which is very big not able to send in single comment.

Comment: markup HTML OFF HEAD "<style type='text/css'> body {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:black; background:White;} p {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:black; background:White;} table,tr,td {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:Black; background:#f7f7e7; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;} th {font:bold 10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#336699; background:#cccc99; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;} h1 {font:16pt Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,

Comment: sans-serif; color:#336699; background-color:White; border-bottom:1px solid #cccc99; margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;} h2 {font:bold 10pt Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif; color:#336699; background-color:White; margin-top:4pt; margin-bottom:0pt;} a {font:9pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#663300; background:#ffffff; margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; vertical-align:top;}</style><title>SQL*Plus Report</title>" BODY "" TABLE "border='1' width='90%' align='center' summary='Script output'" SPOOL OFF ENTMAP ON PREFORMAT OFF

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause the issue. I would try a couple of things: 1 Compare the output of "show all" from the two servers. 2 What is the fullout put of the script; eg: if you just run:  sqlplus -s xxx/xxx << EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
set newpage none
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) from dual;
EOF

Comment: Issue is with Temp space in Unix server.Temp folder is full. After cleaning the Temp space, I am able to get the values from Oracle.

Comment: Glad you figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with Temp space in Unix server.Temp folder is full. After cleaning the Temp space, I am able to get the values from Oracle.